# gcloud auth print-identity-token , how to generate token which will be valid for long term, like some months or year

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, console

In GCP `gcloud auth print-identity-token`

this token is valid for 1 hour around.
how to generate this token, which will be valid for more time, any flag ?

Comment: The maximum lifetime is 1 or 12 hours. Due to clock skew support, subtract 5 minutes from those values. As Guillaume mentioned in his answer, you cannot create long-lived tokens in Google Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

For security reason, it's impossible. The default lifetime is 1h. Thanks to an [organization policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts#extend_oauth_ttl) you can extend the [short-lived token](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct) life duration to 12h. It's the maximum.

Long lived token, like API keys, is not recommended (can be intercepted, stolen, duplicated,...)